# Dual boot if windows was activated

Tags: windows, crash

I heard that if I install ubuntu along with pre-installed windows licensed copy then there are chances that it will crash. Is it true that I should not install Ubuntu if I have an activated licensed copy of Windows preinstalled?

Comment: It does not have anything to do with the license. You can read about certain "risks" here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/risks-dual-booting-windows-linux-operating-systems/

Answer (score 1):

I have Dell Inspiron 5559 Signature Edition which came with Windows 10 Home pre-installed. Its been a year since I've dual booted my laptop. No issues were faced as far as crashes or license is considered.